# ContourPlot with with specific/unequal axis values that cannot be specified in advance

Tags: plotting

I have the following problem:

```
L = 300;

Subscript[β, 0] = 0.0005;

Subscript[ψ, 0] = 0.001;

th1 = 
  Table[
    (Subscript[β, 0]*(Subscript[ψ, 0]*L) - Subscript[β, 1])/(Subscript[β, 1]*L), 
    {Subscript[β, 1], 0.00005, 0.0005, 0.00005}]

lam1 = 
  Table[
    (Subscript[β, 0]*(Subscript[ψ, 0]*L))/(Subscript[ψ, 1]*L + 1), 
    {Subscript[ψ, 1], 0.001, 0.01, 0.0008}]

EZZ = (th1*L + 1)/lam1
```

How can I make a contour plot of EZZ with the $th1$ and $lam1$ values? Both $th1$ and $lam1$ have different length and difficult to compute equal length values for them. Moreover, what should I need to use in $[th1,th1_{min},th1_{max}],[lam1,lam1_{min},lam1_{max}]$ because I dont know exactly the minimum and the maximum of the $th1$ and $lam1$, respectively, but wants to use the values computed in $th1$ and $lam1$.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MathematicaSE. Please format your question as Mathematica code, and not as LaTeX. This way people will be able to copy-paste it and will be more inclined to help.

Comment: Also, $\beta_1$ seems to be initialized in the second row, and then used as a variable in the fourth row. Is this intentional?

Comment: @yohbs. The constants are probably β0 and Ψ0. This is a very bad post even for a first post.

Comment: @m_goldberg I True, but I try to be hospitable nonetheless. Netiquette, like many other things, gets better with practice.

Comment: How can I paste Mathematica code? Sorry for inconvenience but I am new user.

Comment: Please do not post code with MathJaX; code on this site should posted using markdown as explained in the editor help page. You may think the code you posted looks pretty, but it requires anyone who wants to help you retype it into *Mathematica*, and nobody wants to do that. I suggest you read [this thread](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/3066) for advice on pasting code from a _Mathematica_ notebook into our editor pane.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Better, but you must indicate which lines are code. Please click on the little (?) button at the right of the editor's tool bar to learn how to use the tools in the toolbar.

Comment: What is `K`? Is that another constant?

Comment: Contour plots are a way of representing a surface, a function of two variables, on a 2D plot. How does `EZZ` represent a surface?

Comment: As the EZZ is using both the th1 and lam1, that's why one can think it as a surface. I want to see how EZZ changes with the change in th1 and lam1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question, but that has never stopped me before, so here goes:

```
L = 300;
Subscript[β, 0] = 0.0005;
Subscript[ψ, 0] = 0.001;
```

The following definitions contain modifications to the OP's code.

```
th1 = 
  Table[
    {Subscript[β, 1], 
     (Subscript[β, 0]*(Subscript[ψ, 0]*L) - Subscript[β, 1])/(Subscript[β, 1]*L)}, 
    {Subscript[β, 1], 0.00005, 0.0005, 0.00005}];
lam1 = 
  Table[
    {Subscript[ψ, 1], 
     (Subscript[β, 0]*(Subscript[ψ, 0]*L))/(Subscript[ψ, 1]*L + 1)}, 
    {Subscript[ψ, 1], 0.001, 0.01, 0.0008}];
ezz[u_, v_] := (th[u]*L + 1)/lm[v]
```

Now I create a contour plot of `ezz`:

```
th = Interpolation[th1];
lm = Interpolation[lam1];
uDomain = Join[{u}, th["Domain"][[1]]];
vDomain = Join[{v}, lm["Domain"][[1]]];
ContourPlot[ezz[u, v], Evaluate @ uDomain, Evaluate @ vDomain]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much m_goldberg.